# How to pass env variable in scss using stencil-sass plugin

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, sass, stenciljs

I have a requirement in which i have to apply conditional styling by reading environment variable.
If (MODE=PROD)
{prod css link}
else
{dev css link}

```
import { Config } from '@stencil/core'
import { sass } from '@stencil/sass'

export const config: Config = {

plugins: [
 sass('**HERE I NEED TO PASS ENV VARIABLE**')
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the env variable to inject different global paths (see https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-sass#inject-globals-sass-paths):

```js
export const config: Config = {
  plugins: [
    sass({
      injectGlobalPaths: [
        process.env.MY_VAR === 'foo'
          ? 'src/global/variables-one.scss'
          : 'src/global/variables-two.scss',
      ],
    }),
  ],
}
```